# How to find the exact Solution to $ax^2+bx+c= \log(dx)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I have an equation 
$$
ax^2+bx+c=\log{dx}
$$
 How can I solve it?
I know I can use Taylor series to approximately find $x$ but I need an exact solution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Many, many ways. What do you know from numerical methods ? It also depends on the constants.

Comment: What about ways rather than numerical?

Comment: no hope in solving a logarithmic expression involving the same variable as a polynomial expression.

Comment: In general you cannot solve in an exact way. But you can show analytically what is the number and locations of the solution(s) and approximate them with arbitrary precision.